# Translate Python struct.pack to erlang

Tags: python, erlang, pack

I am trying to implement the following python code and get the same result in Erlang:

```
struct.pack('Q', long(20000001))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest equivalent to `pack`/`unpack` in Erlang is achieved using the [bit syntax](http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.6/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html).

As the `Q` format is mapped to the 8 bytes `unsigned long long` by (un)pack, you might obtain something similar by writing:

```
40> <<V:64>>.
<<0,0,0,0,1,49,45,1>>
```

Notice that in Erlang the default endianess is big-endian. You might want to change that (or mention it explicitly):

```
41> <<V:64/big>>.
<<0,0,0,0,1,49,45,1>>

42> <<V:64/little>>.       %% <= Given your example, probably what you want.
<<1,45,49,1,0,0,0,0>>

43> <<V:64/native>>.       %% <= Native endianness 
                           %% -- dependent of the CPU Erlang is running on.
<<1,45,49,1,0,0,0,0>>
```

You can perform the reverse operation using the same syntax (here specifying explicitly the signedness):

```
44> <<B:64/unsigned-big>> = <<V:64>>. %% big-endian (default) to big-endian
45> B.
20000001

46> <<S:64/unsigned-little>> = <<V:64>>. %% big-endian to little-endian
47> S.
84777848354635776

48> <<L:64/unsigned-little>> = <<V:64/little>>. %% little-endian to little-endian
<<1,45,49,1,0,0,0,0>>
49> L.                                         
20000001
```

---

Please note the standard output of binary values might be confusing at first sight when comparing Python to Erlang:

```
Python      Erlang
\x00    =>  <<0>>
\x01    =>  <<1>>
-       =>  <<45>>
1       =>  <<49>>  ! do not confuse the value 1 (0x01) and the character '1' !
```

So, the Python binary string `\x01-1\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00` is written `<<1, 45, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0>>` in Erlang.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am looking for the replacement of packing. Result for struct.pack looks like this: 
struct.pack('Q', long(20000001))
'\x01-1\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Comment: @Gadi ??? As far as I can tell, `<<V:64/little>>` is producing the exact same result as the Python code fragment. I've edited the answer to make that a little bit more clear.